# how to solve the undetermined issue in a let-such-that expression in Dafny?

Tags: set, dafny, formal-languages, formal-methods

here is an example:

```
function intsetmax(s:set<int>):int
  requires |s| > 0
  ensures  var m := intsetmax(s);
           m in s && forall i :: i in s ==> m >= i
{
  var x :| x in s;
  if |s| == 1 then
    assert |s - {x}| == 0;
    x
  else
    var sy := s - {x};
    var y := intsetmax(sy);
    assert forall i :: i in s ==> i in sy || i == x;
    if x > y then x else y
}
```

function 'intsetmax' wants to find the max element in a set, but it shows an error "to be compilable, the value of a let-such-that expression must be uniquely determined", because of the statement "var x :| x in s".

This code works with Dafny versions that are less than 4.0, but it reports an error with 4.0.

So, how to solve it? Do I have to set the function as 'ghost'? Is there any way to get an element in a set?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I consider this to be a bug in the Dafny compiler (i.e. as you can compile such a statement in a `method`).  I'm assuming the bug was introduced in the switch from Dafny 3 to Dafny 4.  See more details [here](https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/issues/4564).

Comment: The difference is that `:|` in a `method` is nondeterministic. That makes it easy to compile. A function has to be deterministic, so if you want to compile `:|`, the compiler has to ensure that you always get the same value back, which can be quite expensive to do at run time. For more details, see https://easychair.org/publications/paper/dM.

Comment: @RustanLeino This implies, however, that `set<T>` is not useful for functions because there is no other way to iterate elements in a `set<T>`.

Comment: A compiled function cannot return an arbitrary element from a set. But there are other useful things you can do in compiled functions, provided you don't in the end depend on which element is returned. An example is a function that sums up the integers of a given set, see https://github.com/dafny-lang/dafny/blob/2a3094a5145e654cdbb22e14f65bee1687d63d17/Source/IntegrationTests/TestFiles/LitTests/LitTest/comp/ByMethodCompilation.dfy#L84. The function body of the `function by method` is ghost, but the method body is compiled, and the nondeterminism in the method body is immaterial for the result.

Answer (score 0):

In versions of Dafny less than 4.0, `function` means `ghost function`. So you should just mark the function as `ghost`.